# Google calendar API location python

Tags: python, location, google-calendar-api

If I already had an event on my google calendar, how can I get its location using Google calendar API in Python?

I tried

`events = events_result.get('items', [])`

to get all the parameters, but I couldn't find 'location'.

So what should I do to get the location of my events?

Comment: What's `events_result`? What does `events` have? Did you look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) will show you the syntax of the event resource returned by the method `Events: get`:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "etag": "\"XXX\"",
 "id": "XXX",
 "status": "confirmed",
 "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?XXX",
 "created": "2020-01-27T10:39:35.000Z",
 "updated": "2020-01-27T10:39:35.800Z",
 "summary": "event with location",
 "location": "home",
 "creator": {
  "email": "XXX",
  "self": true
 },
...
}
```

Consequently, you can retrieve the location in Python by adding the lines:

```py
for event in events:
        print(event['location'])
```

If you cannot retrieve this location - probably it means that the event does not have a specified location.

Comment: Sorry, there was a backslash missing.

Comment: I succeed after I remove the ","

```for event in events:
        print(event['location'])
```

Thanks for your help.